# What is an asset and what is a bundle

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I am new to JavaScript and its related framework.

What is an asset? Is it a group of JS/HTML/img files? Is it a folder? Or a library? Or a generic term used to describe all UI related files?

What is a bundle?

Comment: "Asset" is not a Javascript specific term, an asset is just anything you need to create your project(images, text, video, audio, etc). "Bundle" could refer to many different things, do you mean [module bundling](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-part-2-module-bundling-5020383cf306#.a9p7ezy9h)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An `asset` is typically a static file such as JS files, image files, CSS files. A `bundle` is when those files are then compressed together into a single file.

For example, if you create a "bundle" you can say: Take `layout.js`, `product.js`, `print.js` and output to `my_bundle_name.js`. Usually making a single concatenated minified file called bundle.